# How to process the 'filter' from QueryInfo in odata4j

Tags: java, odata, odata4j

My RESTful web service is passing my Producer some filter information in their request.  For example their URL includes :-
/ACCOUNT-LIST?$filter=Id eq '45012'

How do I process this in odata4j?

From the odata4j JavaDoc I can see that the filter is of type BoolCommonExpression, but can't see any documentation or examples on how I process this.

Also how do I process more than 1 filter option being passed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BoolCommonExpression is the base type of an expression hierarchy (including compound expressions).

You can do instanceof checks or use .visit(ExpressionVisitor) to handle each expression type differently.

Hope that helps,

- john

Comment: Thanks John.  I also found some code in one of the odata4j producers that came with the download - DatastoreProducer.java.